# Adding item to select selectize

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

I'm totally new in javascript and i have a question about slectize library. How can I add something to list and make it selected?

```
{% block head %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'plugins/selectize/dist/css/selectize.default.css' %}">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'plugins/selectize/dist/js/standalone/selectize.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

    var options=[
        {value:0, text:"option 0"},
        {value:1, text:"option 1"},
        {value:2, text:"option 2"},
        {value:3, text:"option 3"},
    ];

        $('show_something').selectize({
        plugins: ['remove_button', 'restore_on_backspace'],
        options: 'options'
        });
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post">
<label>whatever
    <show_something></show_something>
</label>
```

And I can do nothing with it. And I need to select `option 0` and `option 1` by default and have posibilities to choose `option 2` and `option 3`.

I cannot find any informations how to do that simply thing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I know now :P half hour googling more :P

```
{% block head %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 
'plugins/selectize/dist/css/selectize.default.css' %}">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 
'plugins/selectize/dist/js/standalone/selectize.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

var options1=[{
                value: 0,
                title: 'option 0',
            }, {
                value: 1,
                title: 'option 1',
            }, {
                value: 2,
                title: 'option 2',
            }, {
                value: 3,
                title: 'option 2',
        }];

    $('#show_something').selectize({
            plugins: ['remove_button', 'restore_on_backspace'],
            maxItems: null,
            valueField: 'value',
            labelField: 'title',
            searchField: 'title',
            options: options1,
            create: false
        });
});
</script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post">
<selectize id="show_something" multiple="multiple" placeholder="whatever" 
style="width:100px; height:25px;" class="selectized"></selectize>
</form>
```